# C check switch after error

Tags: c, pic

This is a very basic function which is just checking a switch to see if it is open or closed. The problem I am having is when I power up initially and if the switch is open it does not recognize it, however if I close the switch and open again it recognizes it. This problem only occurs the very first time after the chip is programmed. i have checked my init() and everything seems ok, I am not setting the switch to be open anywhere. Could anyone guide me to something I should be looking out for

```
{// Check switch
    BS(TRISB,7);                         //  sw port=input.
    DelayMs(2);                          // will rise is  SW open
    if(RB7)
    {
      if(Control.bits.BUND_ENABLE)        // if  alarm enabled
      {
         if(Alarm_Status.bits.b3)            // if  already set
         {
           DU_Reason.bits.EmergencyDialIn=1;// alarm!
         }
      }
      Alarm_Status.bits.b3=0;           //  Sw Open
    }
    else
      Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1;       //  Sw Closed
    BC(TRISB,7);    
}
```

Comment: a: Please try and indent your code. Well laid-out code will have a better chance of answers.  b: use `&&` instead of `if(..) { if(..)...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't keep changing the port direction from input to output. Just set it as an input when your program starts, and leave it that way.

Comment: has to be there actually, if I switch is not being used or not fitted I want to declare as an output to conserve power. Just wondering why it is not flagging the switch being open after initialization but every other time is.

Comment: Ah. It's probably reading the switch correctly, but your attempt to spot the change of state isn't working: You should initialise `Alarm_Status.bits.b3=1 ;` somewhere in your program initialization.

Comment: How are you saving power by setting the switch to be an input?  Very little current flows into the pin while it is an input.